# SQL Query for single table, compare table columns values

Tags: sql

i have one table (A) which has column caseid and citin  ,
 caseid can have same citin , 
i want a query where i want particular citin which  has 2 or more caseid
I tried

```
select a.caseid from A as a 
 where citin in (select citin, caseid from A as c  where c.caseid != a.caseid )
```

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select a.citin, count(a.caseid) 
from A a 
group by a.citin
having count(a.caseid) > 1
```

Comment: I dont know why we need to have "A as a " when we are not going use the same table twice .. and i am getting error in the second line " Sql query not ended properly "

Comment: using alias in this case not gain any goals. But sometimes using aliases is convenient (for auto-completion where typing in some SQL-editiors for example ). Query is fixed (obviously "as" is no need here ).

Answer (score 3):

```
select  a.citin , count(a.caseid) from A a group by a.citin 
having count(a.caseid) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.citin, COUNT(DISTINCT a.caseid)
FROM A a
GROUP BY a.citin
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.caseid) >= 2
```